# linux terminal autocomplete not working properly

Tags: linux, autocomplete, terminal

I want to move a file located in `/home/my_user_name/downloads/file_to_move`,
I start typing in the terminal `mv h<tab>` and `home` appears, I continue `mv home/my<tab>` and `my_user_name` appears, but then when I type `dow<tab>` and nothing appears. Does the terminal work only two-level deep? Can it be fixed?

Comment: Was your working directory / when you tried it? Perhaps you should try `mv /home/…`.

Comment: I've tried both the `/` directory and `/home/my_user_name`. Autocomplete doesn't seem to work with the `cd` command either. Let's say `/` is the current directory, I type `cd h<tab>` and `home` appears, I press `enter` and now I'm in `/home`, I type `cd my<tab>` and `my_user_name` appears, I press `enter`. Now when I'm in `/home/my_user_name`, no autocomplete works.

Comment: What happens when you type <tab> twice?

Comment: It prints the contents of the current directory, which means that I always have to change to the directory where the file I want to move is, which is not user friendly at all.

Comment: Just to clarify, what I actually meant is `/home/my_user_name/dow<tab><tab>`. Wasn't very clear about it.

Comment: Nothing happens in that case.

Comment: Is the downloads directory listed if you `/home/my_user_name/<tab><tab>`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `Downloads` begins with a capital "D" and that is why it was not picked up by autocomplete.